# Navigate Java stack trace in VS Code without debugger

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, stack-trace

I have a Java project and a stack trace for an exception reported from a run of the Java project. There is no way to reproduce the exception, so I cannot attach and debug it.

Is there a way to load a copied stack trace into Visual Studio Code, so I can navigate through the code lines in the stack trace? If it is possible, what extension do I need to install and what are the steps?

(I know that I can achieve similar in IntellJ IDEA)

Example of a similar stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.example.myproject.Book.getTitle(Book.java:16)
        at com.example.myproject.Author.getBookTitles(Author.java:25)
        at com.example.myproject.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:14)
``
```

Comment: @user7294900 Thank you for referencing another SO. The referenced question and answers are about Visual Studio and not about Visual Studio Code.

Comment: If you copy stack trace to java file (inside comment) you can go to class, also if you copy `**.java:[line]` you can go to specific line

Comment: @user7294900 I created new file, copied the stack trace into a comment and switched the mode to Java. However, no magic happened and no links to click and follow to a class or code line. I might not fully understood your proposal or still something is necessary to do in addition.

Comment: This plugin might provide you with the functionality you need? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Fr43nk.seito-openfile

Comment: @Tschallacka thank you for the suggestion. The stack trace doesn't contain paths in the same format as the plug-in expects, so it will recognise only the file name. It might work with a single file, but I cannot understand how it handles several files. Since it requires to copy the stack trace into a file, located somewhere, the closest one might be not the correct one. It is possible work around with the suggestion from earlier comment.

Answer (score -1):

Seems no such extension or tools to let you click the copied stack trace in another file then navigate to the error location.

When we run projects, the error and exception will be displayed in Terminal. We can right-click `Java Progress Console` and select `Move into Editor Area` to make it more readable. **Ctrl+Click** the sentence which includes line number will navigate to the exception location:

[image]